# How to get a pointer on a function's arguments in C?

Tags: c, dynamic, macros, arguments, c-preprocessor

Is there a generic method to get pointer on each argument in C like
you would do with a vararg function ?

A special syntax like $1, $2, $3

And if not is there some preprocessor macro that define that ?

If not possible in C I'm also interested in a Objective C solution.
I know I can get a selector on current method with _cmd special hidden
parameter. Is there some kind of _arg1, _arg2 ??
Also would it be possible to directly point on memory after _cmd ? Is it
"safe" to consider parameter pointers are next to each other ?

UPDATE TO MY OWN QUESTION

If I access the frame stack by using some assembler code I can get a hold
on the function pointer with ebp right ? So is it possible to access arguments
the same way ? Sorry if this is obvious, I don't know much about assembler.

Comment: Are you asking about passing a pointer to a function?  Or getting a pointer to an argument from inside the function?

Comment: Are you asking about *named* parameters, or *actual* parameters passed in to a "varargs" function?

Comment: I'm pretty sur that doesn't exist. But why do you need that ? You can still give the function the tab pointer (I'm not sur to understand the question).

Comment: I'd like to write some generic code that could work on any function and for that I would need to query at runtime how many arguments a routine has and get a pointer on each of them. The kind of stuff you can do with Ruby or high level languages but I need to do it in C. I'm open to any hacky solution

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but the answer to what you ask is "no".  C functions aren't manipulable at runtime in the same way lots of languages do.  Why don't you edit your question to explain what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is possible but perhaps not entirely useful in your case would be to extract the current and previous stack frame pointers (i e bp register) and, using the standard stack frame structure, determine how many 4 byte (for a 32-bit application) parameter units have been passed in the call to the current routine. You won't be able to determine which units are char, short or long and if two of them together might be a long long/__int64 parameter.

---

I've thought about this some more. Consider a typical function call "func (a,b)". The calling code unless you have parameters in registers (some x86-32 compiler options and intel recommended for x86-64) the code would turn out like this

```
               ; long *esp,*ebp;
push b         ; *(--esp)=b;
push a         ; *(--esp)=a;
call func      ; *(--esp)=return_address_location;
return_address_location:
add esp,8      ; esp+=2;    // free memory allocated for passing parameters
```

Then you come to processing in func

```
func:
push ebp       ; *(--esp)=(long) ebp;    // save current ebp <=> current stack frame 
mov ebp,esp    ; ebp=esp;                // create new stack frame in ebp
sub esp,16     ; esp-=4;                 // reserve space for local variables <=> sizeof(long)*4

(func code ...)
```

Now when you're in func and you need access to parameters you address them with ebp+2 and ebp+3 (*ebp contains previous ebp, ebp+1 the return address. When you need access to local variables you address them with ebp-4 to ebp-1 (may be over-simplified if they are not all longs and you have some packing option set).

After a while func has done its thing and you need to return:

```
mov esp,ebp    ; esp=ebp;         // unreserve space for local variables
pop ebp        ; ebp=*(esp++);    // restore previous ebp <=> previous stack frame
ret            ; eip=*(esp++);    // pop return address into instruction pointer
```

From the first snippet you will also see how the first stack allocation (for passing parameters) is freed right after returning.

A few tips:

- Do the math for yourself while
  single-stepping (instruction by
  instruction) through a call/return
  sequence and you'll get ideas on how
  to solve the original problem. This
  is basic stack handling which looks
  more or less the same on all
  architectures and implementations so
  it's a good thing to know
- Imagine an incorrectly calculated
  memset/memcpy to a local buffer and
  how it will destroy the data on the
  stack including return addresses,
  previous stack frames etc
- Take note of the values in ds and ss
  (data and stack selectors) and if
  they contain the exact same value a
  solution of yours could use memcpy to
  copy the parameters from the stack to
  data memory for examination or
  whatever if that helps
- If ds=ss you can use & to find the
  address of the passed parameters from
  inside func (&param1, &param2)
- If ds and ss or not equal (as they
  might be in a multi-threaded
  application) you will need a
  memcpy variant that uses "far
  addressing" which will handle the
  situation where ds and ss differ

Comment: Yes I was thinking about something like though I have no idea how to do it yet.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the detailed answer ! That definitely put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only way you could do this is with the [`va_list`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) macros provided in `stdarg.h`

Answer (score 0):

See [`stdarg(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) and a [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a special way to do that, or any special notation.

I suppose you could define a macro to take each argument and generate a pointer to it (find the Boost preprocessor library); I'm sure I wouldn't want to.

```
int somefunc(int arg1, char *arg2)
{
    int *p_arg1 = &arg1;
    char **p_arg2 = &arg2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all arguments to a variadic function have the same type (e.g. `void *`), you can do something like this:

```
type nth_arg(va_list ap, size_t n)
{
    va_list ap2;
    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    while (n--) va_arg(ap2, type);
    return va_arg(ap2, type);
}
```

Replace `type` with the actual type.